# AutoHotkey strokes aren't all taking effect

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to create an Autohotkey hotkey that will collapse a tree list that has no collapse all button.  I can collapse this by repeatedly pressing left and then down.  I added this hotkey:

```
!NumpadSub::
Loop 10
    Send,{Left}{Down}
return
```

Yet, when I try it in notepad or OneNote, it just moves the cursor 10 spots left.  When I try in on my tree list, nothing happens.  Do I need to add in delays? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

As I don't know what application this is, I can only guess that a small delay may be the right thing. You might try the following.

```
!NumpadSub::
Loop 10
    Send, {Left}
    Sleep, 200 ; Wait 200 ms
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 200 ; Wait 200 ms
return
```

Patric,

So you don't have these (+) and (-) in front of the directories to collaps them?
[image: Directory Structure in Notepad]
When I press <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>v</kbd>, nothing happens in the notepad directories though.

Comment: I'd expect it to move the cursor down and left in Notepad and OneNote. I'll try delays.